# Как отобразить полный текст при наведении курсора без переноса текста?

Tags: css

Проблема в следующем: есть список (дерево страниц) с position: absolute, некоторые страницы имеют длинное название и не отображаются полностью, выходят за границы блока, где этот список отображается вот так:

[image: вот так:]

Дефолтный системный CSS-код контейнера, где расположен список:

```
.page-tree {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 40px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #F5F5F5;}


.page-tree .page-tree-elements {
display: block;
float: left;}

.page-tree .page-tree-elements>a {
white-space: nowrap;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 10px;}
```

Нужно, чтобы при наведении курсора на элемент списка, показывалось все его название поверх полосы прокрутки вот так:

[image: вот так:]

Добавленный стиль при наведении курсора следующий:

```
.page-tree .page-tree-elements>a:hover {
z-index: 9999;
position: fixed;
}
```

Но! Т.к. позиция фиксированная, при скроллинге дерева страниц элементы, на которые наводится курсор, начинают скакать на свое место, как если бы дерево не скроллилось (что, в целом, логично :) ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать? Пробовались другие position (absolute, relative) - не работает.

Comment: `<a href="//site.com/link.html" title="Очень длинное название">Короткое название</a>`

Comment: Подсказка не подходит, к сожалению, нужно избегать дублирование текста.

Comment: Хорошо, чтобы дать более подходящий совет нужно видеть минимальный код иллюстрирующий проблему. Добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Добавила стили.

Answer (score 1):

CSS и JS only. Недостаток описан в коде HTML.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oCurrElem, oTempElem;
  document.querySelector('.page-tree-elements').addEventListener('mouseover', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName && ev.target.tagName == 'A' && ev.target != oCurrElem) {
      oCurrElem = ev.target;
      oTempElem = oCurrElem.cloneNode(true);
      oTempElem.classList.add('temp_elem');
      oTempElem.style.top = oCurrElem.offsetTop - this.scrollTop - 4 + 'px';
      oTempElem.style.left = oCurrElem.offsetLeft - 1 + 'px';
      oTempElem.addEventListener('mouseover', function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
      });
      oTempElem.addEventListener('mouseout', function(ev) {
        this.remove();
      });
      oTempElem = this.parentElement.insertBefore(oTempElem, this);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page-tree-elements {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.temp_elem {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px dotted #090;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.page-tree-elements>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-tree-elements">
  <a href="#">Чтобы отобразить</a>
  <a href="#">текст, который не</a>
  <a href="#">влезает полностью,</a>
  <a href="#">нужно при наведении</a>
  <a href="#">считывать содержимое</a>
  <a href="#">элемента и дублировать</a>
  <a href="#">его поверх, используя JS</a>
  <a href="#">и создавая временные узлы.</a>
  <a href="#">Данный подход имеет сильное</a>
  <a href="#">ограничение по быстродействию:</a>
  <a href="#">если быстро провести по пунктам,</a>
  <a href="#">то элементы не успевают удаляться.</a>
</div>
```